# How to tell if a string has exactly 8 1's and 0's in it in python

Tags: python

I want to return a boolean value `True` or `False` depending on if the string contains only 1's and 0's.

The string has to be composed of 8 1's or 0's and nothing else.

If it only contains 1's or 0's, it will return `True` and if not it will return `False`.

```
def isItBinary(aString):
    if aString == 1 or 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

This is what I have so far but I'm just not sure how to compare it to both of the numbers as well as see if it has a length of 8 1's and 0's.

Comment: I would iterate through the string and check each character.

Comment: That won't do. You will need to check char by char.

Comment: delete everything except 1/0, then see if what's left is 8 chars long. or check for 8 chars in length, and contains something OTHER than 1/0, e.g. `/^[01]{8}$/` as a regex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [all](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) for this and check the length to make sure it is exactly 8.

```
all(c in '10' for c in aString) and len(aString) == 8
```

Example:

```
aString = '11110000'
all(c in '10' for c in aString) and len(aString) == 8
>>> True
```

The main benefit of doing this over other methods is that it will short-circuit if it finds anything but a zero or one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `set` here. Example -

```
def isItBinary(aString):
    seta = set(aString)
    if seta.issubset('10') and len(aString) == 8:
        reutrn True
    return False
```

Answer (score 2):

```
len(aString) == 8 and set(aString) <= {"0", "1"}
```

The operator `<=` means “is a subset of” here.

Comment: @DSM: I've tried just a False case. I was testing for a syntax error. My bad.

Comment: This is actually quite a nice solution, although you could mention that `<=` means "subset".

Comment: @mkrieger1: Thanks, I've added the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
def isItBinary(aString):
  return all([char in '01' for c in aString]+[len(aString)==8])
```

Answer (score 1):

I like lambda over for loops

```
>>> str = '10001010'
>>> len(str) == 8 and len(filter(lambda bool: not bool, map(lambda bit: bit in '01', str))) == 0
True
```

Comment: Some IDEs and perhaps people will complain about this because `filter` and `map` are rather inefficient with lambdas. (With built-ins like `map(str, some_list)` they are fine).

Comment: `map(lambda x: f(x), values)` seems rather convoluted compared to `[f(x) for x in values]`.

Comment: And `len(filter(lambda x: not x, values)) == 0` is an even more convoluted way for writing `all(values)`.

Comment: Didn't realize there was an `all` operation. Thank you for showing me the light.

Answer (score 1):

If your string is to represent an 8-bit binary number, you could try to convert it as such in your test:

```
def isItBinary(s):
    try:
        return len(s)==8 and int(s,2) < 256
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Comment: How can an 8-bit value not be smaller than 256?